# Creating a folder and setting permissions - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a folder and set permissions on those folders within one PowerShell script. The script won't change the permissions when run the first time. I have to run the script twice to set the permissions. Not sure what could be causing this odd behavior.

```
$desired_install_loc = ${env:ProgramFiles}

$base_path = Join-Path $desired_install_loc 'Base_Test';
$install_path = Join-Path $base_path 'Install_Test';




function Create-Directory {
    if( !(Test-Path $base_path )){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $base_path;
    }

    if( !(Test-path $install_path) ){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $install_path;
    }
}

function Replace-FolderPerms($folder_path) {
    $acl = (Get-Acl -Path $folder_path);
    $add_rule = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("BUILTIN\Users","Read", "Allow"));

    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$true)
    $acl.SetAccessRule($add_rule)

    Set-ACL $folder_path $acl;
}

Create-Directory;

Replace-FolderPerms $base_path;
Replace-FolderPerms $install_path;
```

Creates the folders, but does not set the permissions afterwards.

Comment: Sorry about that, it was the old function name. Should have named it Replace-FolderPerms. It's changing ReadAndExecute permissions to just Read permission for the Users group. I edited the script to replace the function name.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon That worked, thank you! I thought I could keep the previous permissions and just modify it by setting both to $true. I ended up not having to use RemoveAccessRule since the previous permissions we're wiped away. I had to create new permissions for Administrator and SYSTEM, which does the job.

Answer (score 1):

I was attempting to keep old permissions by setting [`SetAccessRuleProtection($true, $true)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection?view=net-7.0). Setting the second argument to `$false` and fully building out the permissions did the trick.

```bash
$desired_install_loc = ${env:ProgramFiles}

$base_path = Join-Path $desired_install_loc 'Base_Test';
$install_path = Join-Path $base_path 'Install_Test';

function Create-Directory {
    if( !(Test-Path $base_path )){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $base_path;
    }

    if( !(Test-path $install_path) ){
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $install_path;
    }
}

function Replace-FolderPerms($folder_path) {
    $acl = (Get-Acl -Path $folder_path);
    
    $add_rule = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("BUILTIN\Users","Read", "Allow"));
    $add_rule_admin = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("BUILTIN\Administrators", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"));
    $add_rule_system = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("SYSTEM", "FullControl", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"));

    $acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false);
    
    $acl.AddAccessRule($add_rule);
    $acl.AddAccessRule($add_rule_admin);
    $acl.AddAccessRule($add_rule_system);
    
    $acl | Set-ACL -Path $folder_path;
}

Create-Directory;

Replace-FolderPerms $base_path;
Replace-FolderPerms $install_path;
```